# How to find my App Store ID and Team ID from free Apple developers account

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, app-store

I'm developing my first Flutter ios app and have created a free Apple Developers account. In order to use Firebase Dynamic Links you need to add your App Store ID and Team ID. Where can I find those? Do I need to sign up to the Apple Developer Program?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you will need to enroll for the Apple developer program. After that you will get those details.

`Team ID` will be available at below link.

https://developer.apple.com/account/#!/membership/

`Apple ID` will be available in the below link.

Visit : https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/apps

Click on your app. Create new app if you don't have one.

Then click on `App Information` at the left side which will open a new window where you will find Apple ID

Comment: You will need a paid account to create app records in App Store connect

Answer (score 0):

Apple Id is also visible in the url when we click on the app.

```
https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/apps/<apple_id_is_here>/...
```